# Route 53 - Should I duplicate my SPF records as TXT records?

Tags: domain-name-system, spf, amazon-route53

Amazon Route 53 supports both "SPF Records" and "TXT Records". Most documentation I read tells me to list my SPF Record as a TXT Record. I understand that the SPF Record is a newer standard. Is it therefore correct for me to duplicate my SPF Records so they're listed as an SPF Records and a TXT Record to ensure backwards compatibility while also following the new standard? I'm unfamiliar with DNS so not sure if this would cause any problems or if I should even bother duplicating them?

My records are as follows:

```
"v=spf1 include:_spf.google.com include:amazonses.com -all"
"spf2.0/pra include:_spf.google.com include:amazonses.com -all"
```

Comment: Short answer: yes.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's not actually correct that the `SPF` RR type is the newer standard (in the context of desired SPF behavior). The [experimental phase of the SPF specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4408#section-3.1.1) had a new record type assigned but the migration path was unclear and it has since been abandoned.

The [current version of the SPF spec](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7208#section-3.1) specifically states:

> SPF records **MUST be published as a DNS TXT (type 16) Resource
> Record**    (RR) [RFC1035] **only**.  The character content of the record is
> encoded    as [US-ASCII].  Use of alternative DNS RR types was
> supported in    SPF's experimental phase but has been discontinued.
>
> In 2003, when SPF was first being developed, the requirements for
> assignment of a new DNS RR type were considerably more stringent than
> they are now.  Additionally, support for easy deployment of new DNS
> RR types was not widely deployed in DNS servers and provisioning
> systems.  As a result, developers of SPF found it easier and more
> practical to use the TXT RR type for SPF records.
>
> In its review of [RFC4408], the SPFbis working group concluded that
> its dual RR type transition model was fundamentally flawed since it
> contained no common RR type that implementers were required to serve
> and required to check.  Many alternatives were considered to resolve
> this issue, but ultimately the working group concluded that
> significant migration to the SPF RR type in the foreseeable future
> was very unlikely and that the best solution for resolving this
> interoperability issue was to drop support for the SPF RR type from
> SPF version 1.  See Appendix A of [RFC6686] for further information.
>
> The circumstances surrounding SPF's initial deployment a decade ago
> are unique.  If a future update to SPF were developed that did not
> reuse existing SPF records, it could use the SPF RR type.  SPF's use
> of the TXT RR type for structured data should in no way be taken as
> precedent for future protocol designers.  Further discussion of
> design considerations when using new DNS RR types can be found in
> [RFC5507].

As a sidenote, there was also a Sender ID record (unfortunately referred to as "spf2.0" despite it being a different spec) in your example, the rules for that type of record are still experimental and [match the experimental version of the SPF spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4406#section-4.3), no updates have been published.

Comment: Thanks, for your detailed answer. In regards to the Sender ID record should that also just be placed as TXT?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, duplicate them; I don't know offhand what ratio of SPF checkers actually support the current standard for record type, but if I were to make a wild guess I'd wager that probably 10% of checkers won't look at an `SPF` record, only `TXT`.

Comment: The [current SPF standard](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7208#section-3.1) says to only use `TXT`